# nesting alert dialog box within progress dialog

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I'm very new in android and I'm developing an application that passes data from android to MySQL through PHP.Now i'm trying to validate login id and password.if any one of the fields is not set or if login id and password is wrong i want to show a alert dialog informing users that login id or password is incorrect.For that i hav written the following code.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity 
{

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url_check_voter = "http://10.0.2.2/evoting/check_voter.php";
    private EditText getUserId;
    private EditText getPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;//private Button btnRegister;
    private TextView lblResult;
    private Button btnRegister;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;

    String TAG_SUCCESS="success" ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        getUserId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getLoginIdTxt);
        getPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPasswordTxt);

        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);




         btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
             public void onClick(View view) 
             {

             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
             }

         });



 // Set Click Listener
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {

             public void onClick(View view) 
             {
                new CheckVoter().execute();
               // Check Login
                 /* String userid = getUserId.getText().toString();
                  String password = getPassword.getText().toString();

                  if(userid.equals(""))
                  {
                     if(password.equals(""))
                          onClick(view);
                     else
                     {
                       lblResult.setText("Wrong password");
                     }

                   } else {
                      lblResult.setText("Username does not exist. Please register.");
                   }*/

               } 

           });




      }

     /* public void onClick(View v)
      {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLogin) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateVoterSuccess.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


}*/





class CheckVoter extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Verifying Voter. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        String loginId = getUserId.getText().toString();
        String pwd = getPassword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginId", loginId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", pwd));
       // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_voter,
                "POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        // Building Parameters
        //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // Building Parameters

        // getting JSON string from URL
        //JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_voter, "GET", params);
       // Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());


        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) 
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   

            }else if(success == 2)
            {
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginFail.class);
              //  startActivity(i);

                alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        HomeActivity.this);
                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Incorrect user name or password");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("click ohk to enter username or password")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                HomeActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });

                    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            }
            else
            {
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateVoterFail.class);
              //  startActivity(i);

                alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        HomeActivity.this);
                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Incorrect user name or password");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("click ohk to enter username or password")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                HomeActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
     }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

and inserted alert box here...

```
else 
            {
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginFail.class);
              //  startActivity(i);

                alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        HomeActivity.this);
                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Incorrect user name or password");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("click ohk to enter username or password")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                HomeActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });

                    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            }
```

I  am getting run time error log cat is as follows

```
09-29 09:54:56.853: D/Create Response(279): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":0}
09-29 09:54:56.853: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-29 09:54:56.983: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2836 objects / 170040 bytes in 118ms
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:801)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:220)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-29 09:54:56.983: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 4 more
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279): Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f00418 that was originally added here
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f00418 that was originally added here
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.onPreExecute(HomeActivity.java:134)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:74)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-29 09:54:57.793: E/WindowManager(279):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 09:54:59.273: I/Process(279): Sending signal. PID: 279 SIG: 9
09-29 09:56:18.005: D/Create Response(313): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":0}
09-29 09:56:18.013: W/dalvikvm(313): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-29 09:56:18.153: D/dalvikvm(313): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2867 objects / 171224 bytes in 123ms
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:220)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-29 09:56:18.153: E/AndroidRuntime(313):  ... 4 more
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313): Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f00510 that was originally added here
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f00510 that was originally added here
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.onPreExecute(HomeActivity.java:134)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:74)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-29 09:56:18.994: E/WindowManager(313):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 09:56:48.843: I/Process(313): Sending signal. PID: 313 SIG: 9
09-29 10:09:07.483: D/Create Response(338): {"message":"Product successfully created.","success":0}
09-29 10:09:07.483: W/dalvikvm(338): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-29 10:09:07.523: D/dalvikvm(338): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2883 objects / 171944 bytes in 41ms
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:59)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:786)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:220)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-29 10:09:07.533: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  ... 4 more
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338): Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f003e0 that was originally added here
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.evoting.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f003e0 that was originally added here
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$CheckVoter.onPreExecute(HomeActivity.java:134)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at com.example.evoting.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:74)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-29 10:09:08.153: E/WindowManager(338):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Java can talk to MySQL directly.  Why do you need to pass it through PHP?  I'm a bit confused at that part.

Comment: As im very new to android,i saw some tutorials for this part...just followed that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground` works on a background thread so you won't be able to update the `UI` in this method.

If you are looking to update the `UI` to the user, you need to implement `onPostExecute` in your `ASyncTask` to display a `Dialog` (or something similar) to inform the user if an error occured.

You can use this block inside any thread to update the `UI` stuffs.

```
Runnable run_in_ui = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your UI stuffs here
    }
};
runOnUiThread(run_in_ui);
```

Comment: you can also can `runOnUIThread()` from `doInBackground()` to update the UI.